# Problem with dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

Hello
I want to create a dll with some functions. For starters I'm trying to do some simple example to just test. I'm creating a new class library with for example such code as below.
When I build it (no error) and create a dll file, I try to use it in my other project by

```
[DllImport("nllibrary.dll")]  
 public static extern long Add(long i, long j);
```

I can compile it but when I try to run the app , it gives me error "cannot find entry point". And when I look at this dll with depends.exe it shows no functions in the dll.
What is wrong with my dll?

The code of the dll:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  


namespace nlLibrary  
{  
    public class nlClass
    {  

        public static long Add(long i, long j)
        {
            return (i + j*2);
        }           
    }      
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `DllImport` for that.

Comment: Console App? Do you have an entry point such as Main defined, out of the box you should see something like  static int Main(string[] args) as the entry point which can be changed, are you calling nlLibrary.nlClass.Add() there or ...?

Comment: Also yea, you don't need a DLL Import just a reference to the Assembly you created

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use the [`[DllImport]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attribute. That's for calling unmanaged C/C++ libraries. For .NET you simply add the generated DLL to the project references and use it directly:

[image]

So for example if you have two projects in your Visual Studio solution called Proj1 (class library) and Proj2 (console application) you right click on the References of Proj2 and select Proj1 from the Project References Tab. Then you simply use the class directly:

```
long result = nlClass.Add(1, 3);
```

after having added the proper using to the namespace:

```
using nlLibrary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you cannot run a DLL.  When you try to run a dll (debug) it will give you that error message.  If you want to test your DLL, look into creating a [test project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182413%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't run the dll. I've added it to other project (windows form).

Comment: @rodro: You have to make sure the forms project is the default project.  Right-click on it and select "Set as Startup Project."  Your DLL is now your startup project.